# append two javascript objects together

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I am needing to add one object to another and not sure how.I need to add phonegroup to the forward object that is inside of the frontdesk object. Does anyone know how this can be done? mind you there is potential for a different object to be attached to forward as well so this has to be something that is scale-able

```
var frontdesk = {
    "frontdesk": {
        "user": "",
        "waittime": "",
        "forward": {}
    }
}

var phonegroup = {
    "phonegroup": {
        "name": "",
        "users": [
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ],
        "noanswer": {
            "forwardafterrings": "",
            "forwardafterseconds": "",
            "forwardto": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forward is empty... do you really need to join the objects, or can you simply replace forward with phonegroup?

```
frontdesk.frontdesk.forward = phonegroup;
```

will do it, if you can simply replace the object.

Answer (score 3):

Try this using [extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
var object = $.extend({}, frontdesk, phonegroup);
console.log(object);
```